# Mojarra 2.1.29 not compatible with JDK 1.6

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I am upgrading my application to primefaces 5.1 and Mojarra javax.faces 2.1.29 version.Before I was using JDK 1.7 at that time I was not getting any error.
To make compatible with client environment I have changed weblogic JDK runtime and  My Eclipse compiler to set 
JDK 1.6 and I am getting below error.Is anyone has faced the same issue? Do I need to use the lower version
of Mojarra 2.1.28 or 2.1.27 with JDK 1.6

```
Jan 6, 2015 2:12:17 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/myHTML.xhtml]
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:373)
                at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:392)
                at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:391)
                at java.util.AbstractMap.equals(AbstractMap.java:420)
                at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.equals(Collections.java:2020)
                at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:138)
                at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:61)
                at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:243)
                at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
                at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:113)
                at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
                at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:464)
                at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
                at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
                at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
                at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
```

Comment: The text implies that you upgraded PrimeFaces to 5.1 and downgraded JDK to 1.6 along. This JDK regression should not be the said problem but the PrimeFaces upgrade should be. What version of PrimeFaces was before? The latest version of PrimeFaces - 5.1 should hardly be compatible with JSF 2.1.x (not sure though). It should at least be expecting JSF 2.2.x.

Comment: Before primefaces version was 5.0.Application working fine with Primefaces 5.1, JSF 2.1.28 and JDK 1.6.This error is coming if application uses primefaces 5.1, JSF 2.1.29 and JDK 1.6.So I believe problem is with JSF 2.1.29 version with JDK 1.6

Comment: [In PrimeFaces 5.1 User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html), it is mentioned, "*PrimeFaces only  requires a JAVA 5+ runtime and a JSF  2.x implementation  as  mandatory dependencies. There’re some optional libraries for certain features like commons-fileupload, commons-io...*" and "*PrimeFaces supports JSF 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2 runtimes at the same time using feature detection and by not having compile time dependency to a specific version. As a result some features are only available depending on the runtime*". To be continued.

Comment: "*A good example for runtime compatibility is the passthrough attributes, a JSF 2.2 specific feature to
display dynamic attributes*" In addition to that Optimus Prime himself responded to [this comment](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3099#comment-6835), PrimeFaces 5.0  is compatible with JSF 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2. (Therefore, PrimeFaces 5.1 should also be fully compatible with those said JSF versions, since PrimeFaces 5.1 is a drop-in replacement of PrimeFaces 5.0). To be continued.

Comment: In a nutshell, the problem should then be on the other side - neither JDK not PrimeFaces (in addition to the said JSF version) appear to be the cause of the said the exception. Doesn't your application itself gives you troubles. Not sure though, I have just copy/pasted some text from somewhere else.

Comment: Anyone know if the issue can be fixed upgrading to 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

Its really strange, but you are right. It`s matter of JDK version. In my situation I encountered the same error while using JDK 1.6.0-30, JSF 2.1.29 on Glassfish 3.1.2-11.

After your suggestion I changed JDK to 1.7.0-45 and the problem was gone.